# selecting rows which have occurred more than three times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table active_users and from that i want to select the rows where user_id has occurred more than 2 times and notified = 0 .Want single result only

[image]

Query Result Required

```
Id   User_id   Mobile      last_seen              notified
1    25853     XXXXXXXX    14-May-2016 17:11:12   0
```

Comment: Why more than twice? That means only 3 times and more. Did you mean more than once, all duplicates?

Comment: occurred 3 times and more ...

Comment: *"occurred 3 times and more* - and your question reads *"has occurred more than 2 times"* - So, which one is it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's the same, (n > 2) == (n >= 3)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone *"more than 2 times"* `n>2` - *"occurred 3 times and more"* `n>=3` - Two different animals here ;-) oh, and an added `=` could be slipped in there, sure.

Comment: You shoud be more specific. What should happen in the case when there are 3 eqal ids, but one of the records is having notified=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM active_users
WHERE notified = 0
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(id) >2
```

Comment: This is not correct SQL ANSI syntax and will work somehow only if `sql_mode` in not `only_full_group_by` as should be.

Comment: It works, but Mitkosoft's answer is the full query you should use

Answer (score 1):

Just count and group by user_id (and any other optional properties), together with having clause:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    mobile,
    max(last_seen) AS last_seen,
    notified,
    count(user_id) AS number_of_records
FROM
    active_users
WHERE
    notified = 0
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    mobile,
    notified
HAVING
    count(user_id) > 2
```

This will give you all users occurred 3 times and more into the table.