# Mysql/Linq Get rows with no repeated values without using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, linq, select, row, hierarchy

imagine several tables in a database with some fields:

Table "Builder": ID_BUILDER,  other fields...

Table "Project": ID_PROJECT, ID_BUILDER, ID_RESOURCE, other fields...

Table "Resources": ID_RESOURCE, ID_BUILDER, other fields...

My question is:

How can I get the ID_BUILDER and the Name of that builder that has made just one project (no more) and has used a resource that has not been used by any other? An example that can clarify it could be:

Table Builder
|ID_BUILDER| NAME         |

|----------|--------------|

|1         | GustavEiffel |

|2         | Egypcians    |

|3         | Me           |

Table Projects
|ID_PROJECT| NAME       | ID_BUILDER|

|----------|------------|-----------|

|1         | EiffelTower| 1         |

|2         | LionBelfort| 1         |

|3         | Pyramids   | 2         |

|4         | PaperFlower| 3         |

Table Resources
|ID_RESOURCE| NAME | ID_PROJECTS|

|-----------|------|------------|

|1          | Steel| 1          |

|2          | Stone| 2          |

|2          | Stone| 3          |

|3          | Paper| 4          |

The query would ask for the ID of a builder that has just done one project and the answer should be {3, Me} because Me just has made 1 project and has used just 1 resource not used by any other (Gustav Eiffel has made 2 projects and Egipcians has used stone in their only project Pyramids, but stone has been also been used for LionBelfort project)

I have been trying to use:

- [group by + having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227156/selecting-rows-which-have-occurred-more-than-three-times) or
- [Select rows with same id but different value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column):

But I couldn't get an aswer. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query contains column which counts how many times resource was used in different projects:

```
select p.id_builder, p.name, r.id_resource, 
       count(1) over (partition by id_resource) cnt_resources
from Resources r join Projects p on p.id_project = r.id_projects
```

You can join this subquery with classical group-by-having approach and take only rows which have count_resources=1:

```
select p.id_builder, b.name
from Projects p 
join Builder b on b.id_builder = p.id_builder
join  (select p.id_builder, r.id_resource, 
              count(1) over (partition by id_resource) cnt_resources
       from Resources r join Projects p on p.id_project = r.id_projects) c
  on p.id_builder = c.id_builder and cnt_resources = 1
group by p.id_builder, b.name
having count(1) = 1
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qPariVBy)